# CMake doesn't recognize types of winsock2

Tags: c++, cmake, winsock2

I'm new in CMake and I'm trying to compile my winsock2 project using this, but still getting errors like:

> In file included from /cygdrive/c/Users/Kacper/Desktop/aurea/aurea/includes/WebServer.h:14:0,
>                    from /cygdrive/c/Users/Kacper/Desktop/aurea/aurea/WebServer.cpp:1:
>   /cygdrive/c/Users/Kacper/Desktop/aurea/aurea/includes/HttpServer.h:48:13: error: 'SOCKET' does not name a type
>                SOCKET server_socket

There is my CMakeLists file:

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)
    project(aurea)
    include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/aurea/includes)

    find_library(WS2_32_LIBRARY ws2_32)

    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra")

    file(GLOB SOURCES aurea/*.cpp aurea/http/*.cpp aurea/router/*.cpp aurea/utils/*.cpp)
    file(GLOB HEADERS aurea/includes/*.h)

    add_executable(aurea ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})

    target_link_libraries(aurea ${WS2_32_LIBRARY})
```

Why compiler doesn't recognize types of winsock? :< When I'm trying to compile simple one file project linking ws2_32 like this there is no error, I think I'm wrong in setting sources but can't find mistake by myself.

Comment: Is winsock2 headers properly included? Does your code compile without CMake?

Comment: Sure, when I have created Makefile by myself there were no errors.

Comment: Unless `cmake` injects `#include`s into the C code, then this in not a problem with `cmake`. There is something wrong with the C code, unless, it is picking up a different version of the header-file, because of include paths are different.

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: Make sure your C code has explicit `#include <winsock.h>` or `#include <winsock2.h>` statements in it.

Comment: `I think I'm wrong in setting sources` - You can always check content of CMake variables you set via `message()` command. E.g. `message("SOURCES are: ${SOURCES}")`